# How to call a function from a Class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm studying to be a Game Designer, and right now I'm having some issues with my flash game.

the game has a Counter Class, with a Score Class that extends Counter. and it is added to the stage in my PlayScreenA Class.

The Timer starts with a number and decreases every 24frames. but in my Hero Class I can pick up some coins and that coins are going to increase the Time on my Score.

The question is: How I can say in my Hero Class to execute the addToValue function inside the Counter Class?

Pieces of Code:
Creating my score in the PlayScreenA Class:

```
    private var myTime:Score = new Score();
    private function create_time (){

        myTime.x = 800;
        myTime.y = 50;          
        addChild(myTime);
    }
```

Counter Class:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class Counter extends MovieClip
{
    public var currentValue:Number;

    public function Counter()
    {
        reset();
    }

    public function addToValue( amountToAdd:Number ):void
    {
        currentValue = currentValue + amountToAdd;
        updateDisplay();
    }

    public function subToValue( amountToSub:Number ):void
    {
        currentValue = currentValue - amountToSub;
        updateDisplay();
    }

    public function reset():void
    {
        currentValue = 20;
        updateDisplay();
    }

    public function updateDisplay():void
    {

    }
}
}
```

Score Class:

```
package 
{
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event;
public class Score extends Counter
{
    protected var _timeCounter:int;     

    public function Score()
    {
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onUpdate);
    }
    override public function updateDisplay():void
    {
        super.updateDisplay();
        scoreDisplay.text = currentValue.toString();
    }
    protected function onUpdate(e:Event):void
    {
        _timeCounter++;
        trace(currentValue);

        if (_timeCounter == 24)
        {
            this.subToValue( 1 );
            _timeCounter = 0;
        }           
    }
}
}
```

Piece of my Hero Class where I need to Call the function:

```
for(var i:int; i<collisionList.length;i++)
        {
            var $collision:platform_tile = collisionList[i];

            if($hasCollided = hitbox.hitTestObject($collision.hitBox) && $collision.alpha<0.8 && $collision.alpha>0.6)
            {
                $collision.alpha=0;
                $collision.visible = false;
                //Here is where I want to call my subToValue                                        function!
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to access the object of Score class created initially in the PlayerScreenA class...

If that is the case then you either derive a relationship between the two classes to pass this object or you could keep a static class keeping track of the function at a global level...

```
public class AppRefrences
{
    public static var addToValueFunc:Function;    
}
```

In Player A Class,

```
    private var myTime:Score = new Score();
    private function create_time (){

        myTime.x = 800;
        myTime.y = 50;          
        addChild(myTime);

        // This is where you set the function
        Apprefrences.addToValueFunc = myTime.addToValue;
    }
```

In Hero Class,

```
for(var i:int; i<collisionList.length;i++)
        {
            var $collision:platform_tile = collisionList[i];

            if($hasCollided = hitbox.hitTestObject($collision.hitBox) && $collision.alpha<0.8 && $collision.alpha>0.6)
            {
                $collision.alpha=0;
                $collision.visible = false;

                // This is where you call the function
                if(AppRefrences.addToValueFunc != null) 
                AppRefrences.addToValueFunc(0); 

                break;
            }
```

Try using getter & setters to control the update of the static variable. I didn't include it for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Worked So Sweet!
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm so glad that you could make it work with so few lines of code. Right now I'm just a beginner Programmer for Games, If you have time for a newbie, I'd appreciate if you could take a look in my entire code, and point out what I did poor and How I could improve my logic in a next work. I prefer to talk and send files by email, but I'm up for any other way of contact.
(the game is not even close to be done, but that was my main problem, I don't think I'll have any other hard time now)
My email is gd27marcelo@vfs.com
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

since `addToValue` and `subToValue` are instance methods, you should provide a reference (an instance variable) to the counter object in your hero object, then call its `addToValue` or `subToValue` methods.

```
var theCounter:Counter;
```

you should either initiate this in your hero object, or assign a pre-existing counter object through getter/setters. then you can call:

```
theCounter.addToValue();
```

Comment: Hi, That was really useful and solves almost all the problems similar to mine, But don't works in my case.
When I tried to do your first suggestion. The program runs correctly but Now I get this error every time I pick up a Coin:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Hero/collidesAt()
 at Hero/onUpdate()

If you think that using getter/setters will solve the problem, can you tell me a little bit more about how they work?
if the problem is something else I'd appreciate if you could take a more dip look at my code. ask me what pieces you need

Comment: I don't know how you designed your project, but I guess you should have some kind of main controller which is responsible for initiating necessary objects and start the application, and most probably thats where you should initialize the counter object, then you can pass its reference to the hero object and then the hero object can use it. to do this the Hero class should have a setter for counter...

Comment: See this [link](http://qwickthoughts.blogspot.ca/2007/07/getset-in-actionscript-3-explained.html) for defining getter setters... Also, if the counter is supposed to be the only counter in your app and all other objects supposed to use the same counter, you might wanna go with a singleton design pattern, see this [link](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=192449) to understand how you can turn your counter to a singleton